# Distribution domination for sums of independent random variables in Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(\xi_n)$ and $(\eta_n)$ be independent mean-zero random variables with values in $X$ satisfying
$$
\sum_n \mathbb P(\xi_n \in A) \leq \sum_n \mathbb P(\eta_n \in A),
$$
for any Borel set $A\subset X\setminus \{0\}$.

Please find sufficient and necessary conditions on $X$ and $1\leq p<\infty$ so that there exists a constant $C_{p, X}$ satisfying
$$
\mathbb E \bigl\|\sum_n\xi_n\bigr\|^p \leq C_{p, X} \mathbb E \bigl\|\sum_n\eta_n\bigr\|^p.
$$

---

This problem stated for a general Banach space was originally posed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339029/on-sums-of-independent-random-variables-in-banach-spaces). It turned out that $X$ can not be $\ell^{\infty}$ (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345059/148449)) and that $X$ should have a finite cotype due to the Maurey–Pisier theorem (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345764/148449)).